# search load and replace data from .txt file to and display it in C#

Tags: c#

how can I search load and replace data from .txt file to and display it

my data in txt.file is

```
1010w23#Mild#UnknwonStreet#001234521
```

and I want to change it with this

```
1010w34#Mild#UnknownStreet#001235421
```

I amusing windows form application and I'm new in C#

My save data using this

```
string[] dataEmployee = new string[4];

dataEmployee[0] = txtIdEmployee.Text;
dataEmployee[1] = txtName.Text;
dataEmployee[2] = txtAddress.Text;
dataEmployee[3] = txtContact.Text;

string.Join("#", dataEmployee);

TextWriter writeDataEmployee = new StreamWriter(@"dataemployee.txt", true);
```

Comment: `how can I search load and replace data from .txt file to and display it` Should we write the whole code or do you have a specific question?

Comment: nope just specific code I think
and there all is input from user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like below, it will help you...

Create `4 Text boxes` and `one button` in your Form and name it like below..

**TextBoxes :**

```
txtEmployeeIDFind
txtEmployeeIDReplace
txtContactReplace
txtContactFind
```

**Button:**

```
btnFindandReplace
```

and run the form Now the User enter their value on text box like below

[image]

On the `Button click event` write the Coding like below...

```
   private void btnFindandReplace_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("dataemployee.txt");
        text = text.Replace(txtEmployeeIDFind.Text, txtEmployeeIDReplace.Text).Replace(txtContactFind.Text, txtContactReplace.Text);
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText("dataemployee.txt", text);
    }
```

Comment: but how if 1010w23 and 001234521 is an input from user, and 1010w34, 001235421 is input from user too?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, although without more information we cannot be sure what do you need exactly:

```
string text = File.ReadAllText(fileName);    //fileName is the path to your txt file
string[] fields = text.Split('#');
fields[0] = fields[0].Replace("23", "34");
fields[3] = fields[3].Replace("45", "54");
txtResult.Text = String.Join("#", fields);    //txtResult is some textbox in your form
```

Comment: but how if 1010w23 and 001234521 is an input from user, and 1010w34, 001235421 is input from user too?

Comment: how do you want to change it then? you might just replace whole string in a given array index, like: fields[0] = txtIdEmployee.Text;